# Is a ContentResolver's sync frequency based on device time?

Tags: android, time, synchronization, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

When using a `ContentResolver`, you can set it up to sync periodically using the following call:

`addPeriodicSync(Account account, String authority, Bundle extras, long pollFrequency)`

`pollFrequency` determines how frequently it is allowed to sync. Is this based on the device's clock or does it use some timer that is agnostic of other time mechanisms?